# The mistake in find and sed command in linux?

Tags: linux, sed, find, command

I want add some script to my site.
But problem in one thing: site include hundreds of html files.
So I need to create some command to insert code after body tag. How I can do this?

```
find . -name '*.html' exec sed -i 's/<\/body>/<script src="1.js"><\/script><\/body>/g' {} \;
```

But it can't work.
Please, fix this command

Comment: Any errors? Also there is a typo. You are missing `-` before the exec

Comment: nope. On ubuntu on my server perfectly working. But in other - no.

Comment: How I can add <script> after certain line? for example, I want add <script></script> after 7 line in my html file. I forgot about this flag

Answer (score 0):

That also works for me:

```
find * -name "*.html" | xargs -L1 -I{} sed -i 's/<\/body>/<script src="1.js"><\/script><\/body>/g' {}
```

Changes:

- replaced path `.` with '*'
- the'xargs' tool gets all lines from stdin, and executes command separately for each of line, with possibility to pass that line as argument in command, so
- in that case this is the same approach as `find -cmd`, but generally it opens another possibilites (check out the xargs manual).

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in command - replace `exec` with `-exec` and should be fine.

```
find . -name '*.html' exec sed -i 's/<\/body>/<script src="1.js"><\/script><\/body>/g' {} \;
```